# Regex for removing consecutive character formatting tags

Tags: php, regex, simple-html-dom

I need a regex to match and replace the consecutive character formatting tags enclosing the entire paragraph tags in simple DOM Html Parser

Input :

```
<p><b><i>Lorem Ipsum Content</i></b></p>
```

Expected output : `<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>`

In the below case regex should match and replace only the `<b>` tags since that's the only tag that encloses the entire paragraph tag

eg :Input : `<p><b>Text <i> some more text </i>text inside </b></p>`

output : `<p>Text <i> some more text </i>text inside </p>`

Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will look something like this:

```
foreach($html->find('p') as $p) {
  while(preg_match('/^<([^>]+)>(.*)<\/\1>$/', $p->innertext, $m)){
    $p->innertext = $m[2];
  }
}
```

Note that the `\1` in the regex matches the html tag name from the first capture group, probably not necessary but I did it for the bonus.

Answer (score 0):

Not an elegant and maybe partial soultion.

1. Trim(strip) the `input` string
2. `while True:`
3. Replace `<i>` to `""`
4. Replace `<b>` to `""`
5. Replace etc character tag to `""`
6. ...
7. If no match found during step 3 ~ 6, then `break`.

And the regex for step 3 is this.

```
<p>\s*(<i>)*\s*.*(<\/i>)\s*<\/p>
```

For `<b>` tag, replace `<i>` to `<b>`, etc.